# Why FastAPI views aren't raising argument errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, python-decorators, optional-parameters

I'm trying FastApi for the first time, I can use a view give it for example Request parameter
and then I can use it, but I can remove it from view parameters, it won't raise any argument errors
unlike Django views or any python function, they have specific arguments any change will raise missing argument or function takes two arguments but got three for example
so how can this be any different?

## Example

---

This works

```
@app.get('/home/')
async def HomeView():
    return {'result' : True}
```

and this also works

```
@app.get('/home/')
async def HomeView(request: Request):
    return {'result' : True}
```

why the first one not raising missing required parameter?

Answer (score 1):

> *why the first one not raising missing required parameter?*

Probably the argument is optional since you aren't accessing the variable in the function.

---

Lets say you have something like this:

```
@app.get('/home/')
async def HomeView(request: Request):
    client_host = request.client.host
    return {"client_host": client_host}
```

In this case you **need** `request` to be passed as argument, because you are using it in the body of the function.

---

```
@app.get('/home/')
async def HomeView(request: Request):
    return {'result' : True}
```

In this case it's like `FastAPI` (in particular the `app.get` decorator) is saying something like:

> *Ok, they asked for an argument, and the argument is recieved.*

---

@app.get('/home/')
async def HomeView():
return {'result' : True}

In this case there's an incoming `request`, but you are not *capturing* it as argument in your decored function, because you don't need it.

FastAPI is saying:

> *Ok, they don't need this `request` to be passed as argument. No problem.*

---

You will often find something like this when working with `decorators`, in particular with `API wrappers`, like `Discord.py`.

## Edit

---

> *i found it, `list(func.__annotations__.values())` is used to get function arguments types, then we only need to pass the right parameters using forloop :"*

For sure, the decorator knows the annotations (so the types of the arguments) passed to the function. That's how they can pass non-positional or optional arguments.

Comment: still not enough explaining
if i did this
`
def fun(x):
   print(x)

fun(5, y=10) #will raise an error
`

Comment: Let me try again...

Comment: sorry man, my comment felt really rude

Comment: No problem  it didn't feel rude, now it should be more clear.

Comment: there's only one part, how fastApi knows what parameters the function require
the only way i think of it giving the function all possible parameters with try except many many times until they react the required one, but sure there's a simple one idk about

Comment: i found it, `list(func.__annotations__.values())` is used to get function arguments types, then we only need to pass the right parameters using forloop :"